# Problems when trying to connect my Elixir application to a Postgres bank on the VPN

Tags: postgresql, elixir, vpn

I'm having trouble connecting my elixir application to a postgres database on a VPN. When I run: mix ecto.create, I get the return: ** (Mix) The database for TestDatabase.Repo couldn't be created: ERROR 42501 (insufficient_privilege) permission denied to create database. Could someone give me a "north" of what can be? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As you see, you are getting Postgres' error, not the connection error or something.
This means, that your connection to the database is established, but there are some problems with our connection credentials.

Find these lines in your config files (inside `config` folder), and check that the credentials are right:

```
config :my_app, MyApp.Repo,
    username: "my_super_user",
    password: "Some$ecretpAss",
    database: "database_name_here
```